# Android ScrollView Vs ListView

Tags: android, listview, optimization, view, scrollview

I´m facing the implementation of a View where I have to load perhaps almost 100 items in a list. I have a doubt in which maybe the best way to implement it. 
I already know that `ListView` recycles the views and `ScrollView` keeps all in memory. The point is that I was thinking in apply paging to the `Scrollview` to avoid huge loading times when the app inflates all items.

Applications as Google+, Facebook, twitter or Linkedin, Do you think they use ListView?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ListView is definitely the way to go. It's easier to use than ScrollView, and a paging system doesn't fit in with the style of android.

ListView is meant to create a list of varrying lengths based of an array of information. ScrollView is for having a (usually) set amount of children in the View (defined in the layout xml).

ListViews do not inflate all items, they inflate however many can fit on a page at a time. Your fastest option, with or without paging is a ListView. However, if each child is completeley different, then ScrollView is the way to go.

Comment: There are differences between the children, that's why I've asked adding the examples of Facebook, Google +,... I only wanted to understand how optimise it because at the moment using ScrollView I'm having a huge delay in the step of showing the views, even doing the implementation in other thread.  Thanks for answering and not add more extra negative points.

Comment: What are the differences? And are you adding the views to the scroll view programmatically, or are all views defined in the xml layout? And how are the children different? Are they simply different content or completely different layouts? I have no clue about Facebook, but google+ and Gmail I'm side use ListView

Comment: I´ve managed to find out where was my mistake.As I´m working with pictures inside a item, I was having huge delays when each picture was visible, even with implementing Volley Library with DiskCache.I tried to implement it with Scrollviews and it solved my problem for small amount of items but with a huge list it didn´t work. I didn´t know about [JakeWharton DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache).Combining JackeWharton library with Volley has solved my delay issue then ListView is perfect to work with it. The bottom line is that my approach was wrong with the images. thanks

Comment: @Kylelem62 your answer saved a lot of time. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with all your points except:

"However, if each child is completeley different, then ScrollView is the way to go."

ListView (or specifically Adapter#getItemViewType(int)) supports different listItem types.  It also offers the same aforementioned recycling benefits.  Therefore, I don't think having different listitem types is a reason to use ScrollView.

Comment: If every view is different, you would have to hardcode each view into the ListAdapter. Unless you have a massive amount of views in the scrollview then the ListView is still the way to go.